# When to apply corrections on data gathered from a server

Tags: server, caching

I have an program that collects data from other servers. I don’t have access to these servers so I can’t change anything. The servers can give incorrect data, I can solve the problem but I’m a little bit stuck on “when to do the correction”.

I download the data from the server, the data gets processed and stored on the hard-drive. When the same data is needed an there is no change, then I use the old data. So this is basically caching.

There are 2 places where I could apply the correction.

- When I receive the data from the other servers;
- After I cache the data. So right before I use it.

When I apply the correction on the downloaded data directly, then the server doesn’t need to do much calculations. It’s only corrected once.

When I apply the correction after I took it from the cache or when isn’t cached after I cache the data. Then I need more CPU power. But this gives me the advantage to access the original data at all time. I could fall back when I made a mistake and apply a correct correction.

So the question is, when should I apply the correction? And why should I do it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be a question of performance and dependent on your expected application usage. If your application is going to be downloading the data infrequently but distributing it to users frequently I would do my calculations when writing the data to disk. If you are going to be downloading a lot of data sets from the servers which may never be accessed by a user I would move the processing to when you are getting the data from disk / from a cache.

Quick note here:

> When I apply the correction after I took it from the cache or when isn’t cached after I cache the data. Then I need more CPU power. But this gives me the advantage to access the original data at all time. I could fall back when I made a mistake and apply a correct correction.

There is nothing that says that you couldn't keep both a raw copy of the data as well as a modified one while applying the correction at the time of downloading the data.